# authorize.net response url returning Your script timed out while we were trying to post transaction results to it

Tags: grails, callback, authorize.net

I'm trying to integrate authorize.net's DPM api into my project.  The issue i'm running into is the response url.  I know there is a lot out on the web about this already, but it's all gibberish to me.  The error message is:

```
An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card. 

      This transaction has been approved.
It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the product or service.
```

In my email for this sandbox account I get the following error message:

```
Your script timed out while we were trying to post transaction results to it.
```

In my sandbox account I have

```
http://myIp:8080/myProject/shoppingCart/authorizePayment      Default Receipt URL   Edit
http://myIp:8080/myProject/shoppingCart/paymentAuthorizing    Default Relay Response URL    Edit
```

I have verified i can access myIp from the outside world by navigating through my website using that IP.

On my form I'm sending them:

```
<input name="x_relay_url" value="http://myIp:8080/myProject/shoppingCart/paymentAuthorizing">
```

in my shippingCart controller

```
def paymentAuthorizing(){
    [params: params]
}
```

and my gsp page for the paymentAuthorizing action:

```
<meta name="layout" content="main">
<div>
    Payment Authorizing.  Please Wait
    <g:javascript>
        window.location.href = '<g:createLink action="authorizePayment" params="${params}"></g:createLink>';
    </g:javascript>
</div>
```

it is the number 1 issue posted at

http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/5-Most-Common-Errors/ba-p/35655

but it doesn't seem to be relevant

I have verified I can access my server through the chrome rest client

[image]

Comment: The issue is the sandbox server is unable to POST to your designated URL.  It must be publicly addressable, and it must be a standard port 80 or 443.

Comment: @rhldr it's an HTTP request so it should be at port 80, the fact that the request goes to port 8080 should be irrelevant, since it still comes across the http protocol.

Comment: @rhldr I just posted proof that I can post to my server, and even the callback url

Comment: Yes, you might be able to POST to your own server, but can one from outside your server?  http://goo.gl/1dkhIk shows you the IP addresses where the relay response will POST from.

Comment: @rhldr If I use my external IP address in the url of the post, won't that guarentee someone from outside my server hitting it?  Since i'm using my external IP address I'm technically going outside my server (not using localhost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[rhldr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301651/rhldr) explains the reason for the error in his comment.

The error you are experiencing, and some troubleshooting, is described [here](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Relay-Response-Basics-and-Troubleshooting/ba-p/9536) in the Authorize.net documentation. This is the relevant part:

> If the merchant’s Web server is not available on the public Internet, has authentication enabled, or if the Relay URL uses a non-standard port for HTTP or HTTPS traffic, Relay Response timeouts will occur. Authorize.Net will not have any means to connect to your server or authenticate itself on your server, and can only use ports 80 and 443 for all Web traffic.

I would suggest trying with port 80 or 443 and seeing if that works.

Comment: It uses the standard http protocol.  the 8080 port is the port my application server is on, but it still gets hosted through http

Comment: It's HTTP... HTTP is on port 80.

Comment: It's not on port 80 if you change the port number, HTTP uses port 80 as the default port. http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1976/why-only-port-80-for-web-services

Comment: In my particular case, the HTTP responde code wasn't 200, that's why I was facing this error. I fixed and then it's working properly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The errors that Authorize.Net DPM provide can be very misleading. I have found in my experience, that a timeout often is not a timeout, but just an invalid response. **All** of the following for me have resulted in the error messages you describe:

- A self-signed certificate on your relay target. On our dev environment, I force the relay URL to be non-SSL to get around this.
- A non HTTP 200 response, so any error in your code handling the relay response is likely to cause this, which can be hard to debug because the gateway does not return any details of that error.
- A relay URL that is not registered with the gateway. The gateway needs to know about all of the URLs you are going to use in advance, which means also that you cannot made use of arbitrary GET parameters on that URL.

Comment: In our case, the test server's load balancer was TLS1 only, which is no longer supported by authorize.net. The "self-signed" certificate comment clued me in. We upgraded to TLS1.1/1.2 and the timeout error went away. Much thanks! Great post.